# NSString's hash method and back?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Once I use `[NSString hash]` and get a `NSUInteger`, is there any way I can use that `NSUInteger` and turn it back into the original `NSString`? Apple doesn't really say anything about the implementation of the `hash` method in the docs.

FYI: I'm trying to store `identifierForVendor` as a `NSNumber` (specifically in either the `major` or `minor` property of a `CLBeacon`).

Comment: "is there any way I can use that NSUInteger and turn it back into the original NSString?" - No, by the definition of a hash.

Answer (score 4):

No. The hash is 32 or 64 bits, a string can be much longer, so it is inherently lossy, and the hash values are not unique (the same hash corresponds to multiple strings).

Comment: Say you had some unique string (possibly the device's `identifierForVendor`), and you only had 2 `NSNumber`s to work with for conversion and storage, and you had to make a positive comparison to the original string, what would you do?

Comment: @Yazid, I would start to rethink the design of my application.

Comment: @vikingosegundo No kidding. To elaborate further I'm trying to do a mashup of Multipeer Connectivity and iBeacons, so that connected peers can be linked against iBeacons detected (the devices broadcasting as iBeacons). It's gotten quite hairy. In a quick and dirty implementation, I've simply hashed the `deviceName`s and used that as both the Peer's `displayName` as well as the iBeacon's `major` value, but I'm looking for a more graceful solution (without connecting to some web service, if possible).

Comment: @Yazid, what you try to achieve is just not possible with hashes. The UUID has 128 bits, numbers 32 or 64. You just cannot press any 128 bit into 32 or 64 and reconstruct them lossless. Or mathematically: you cannot create a bijective conversion function, as the number of items in the possible item sets do not match.

Comment: Actually you don't need bijection, but injection. But also that is not provided. You have a case of surjection, where multiple items from set X will point to one item in set Y. X = UUID, Y = nsnumber.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, hash is not supposed to be de-coded. You may want to read something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Apple says "If two string objects are equal (as determined by the isEqualToString: method), they must have the same hash value". That's all you can get.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store it for later comparisons, then you should hash the both `NSString`s & compare the resulting `NSUInteger`s

Comment: Can't store, trying to match a device's `identifierForVendor` via sending data thru Multipeer Connectivity and with values read off the same device acting as an iBeacon, and `CLBeacon` only allows a `proximityUUID` (which is meant to be company-specific), and two other `NSNumbers` (`major` and `minor`).